# CMake - How to include header files of an external linked library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project and I want to use an external library. I use CMake to build my application.

Here are my interesting lines of code:

```
add_executable(my_app ${SOURCES})
find_library(SDSL sdsl)
target_link_libraries(my_app PUBLIC ${SDSL})
```

The static library is found because it is stored in `/lib/libsdsl.a` which is a path where CMake searches libraries. I don't have any link error.

But when I want to include a file from this library, I have a `file not found` error. I can handle it by adding the following line:

```
target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE "/include")
```

Because when I installed the library, the header files where by default, stored in this folder.

But the problem is that my project could be build by another person with another environment. What is the best way to include headers? I mean, `find_library` is looking for pattern like `/lib/lib<libname>.a`, is there a way to ask CMake to look for patterns `/include/<libname>/`?

We can set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to allow CMake to search libraries in different path, So I could add the following line to handle my problem, but it doesn't feel to be a good practice:

```
target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/include")
```

But I'm new in CMake and compilation stuff and I saw a github project where the exact same library is used and I can't compile it because of `file not found` errors. Did I miss something?

Link to the library: [here](https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite/tree/master)
Link to the project which use it and which doesn't compile for me: [here](https://github.com/maxrossi91/r-index/blob/87e59bf2fb0124cd95542db880325abfada67e34/CMakeLists.txt#L33)

Note that this last project is a fork of a fork and each version uses a different way to include the sdsl-library, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Command [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) is a CMake way to find the include directory with a library's header. Like `find_library`, `find_path` searches "standard" directories automatically.

Comment: `find_library(SDSL sdsl)` did you try `find_package(SDSL)` instead? The CMakeLists.txt for `SDSL` looks like it supports the include being set when you do `target_include_libraries(myapp SDSL)` because of the target_inclide_directories here: https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L144

Comment: @drescherjm I agree with the fact that `SDSL`'s CMakeLists.txt allows me to have access to the headers, this is what is done in [this project](https://github.com/alshai/r-index/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L21), by using `add_subdirectory` with a git submodule. But to use `find_package` we need a `FindSDSL.cmake` file somewhere isn't it? And I didn't find any...

Comment: Is there a `SDSLConfig.cmake` or `sdsl-config.cmake` in the build folder for SDSL after you compiled it from the github source?

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, I didn't know this command and it works like a charm. But how can we explain that I can't compile the project I linked, even if I have the required sdsl-library? Maybe this is just because they didn't test it, because when I don't have the library, it compiles, but I hope they did.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm afraid there is no such file. But there is a `CPackConfig.cmake` even if i'm pretty sure this is something else.

Comment: Yes that is for packaging.